# What does "shop i" mean?

Tags: word-request

In this text:

- NAME: Samantha Greenbriar
- YEAR: 11
- TEACHER: Fletcher
- PERIOD: 5
- SUBJECT: Shop I
- ASSIGNMENT: Metalworking - Engraving
- GRADE: C-

What does "shop i" mean?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is Too Localised. Perhaps "Shop 1" here means *[metal]work shop 1*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's pretty universal US usage.

Comment: @StoneyB: There's not a single instance of ["passed shop 1"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22passed+shop+1%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) or ["pass shop 1"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22pass+shop+1%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books. Just one of each on the entire Internet.

Comment: @FumbleFingers True, but when you're in HS everybody knows what year you're in. Leave the number off. Try "flunked shop" (you'll get a lot more with 'passed', but many will be false hits)

Comment: @StoneyB, using the word *year* followed by a number, is normal practice in British schools. The example in this question, *year 11*, would be the last year of secondary school. Maybe the question has a British context?

Comment: @StoneyB: oic. I did actually look for "failed/fail", but that didn't get anything either (we Brits don't use "flunk" that much, so it never came to mind). Okay, I accept that I can hardly claim Americanisms are "Too Localised".

Comment: @Tristan I obviously can't be certain, but it seems more likely to me that a shop class (which would be potentially very dangerous) would be for older students than that. In the US, "year 11" would be 11th grade, when students are ~17.

Comment: @WendiKidd, from the question and some of the answers, it seems that American *shop* is somewhat like British technology/DT classes, which start from year 7 (ages 11-12). Despite that, the word *shop* is not used for British school subjects. The word *period* is used for particular times in the school day when lessons happen. There are different lessons in different periods. The use of that and *year 11*, with *shop*, makes the question unclear and in need of clarification by giving context.

Comment: @WendiKidd, in the UK, *year 11* is for ages 15-16, with 16 being the school leaving age.

Comment: @Tristan Context would definitely be great; I was just trying to make an educated guess :) *Period* is used in American schools as well, though you don't have different classes in each period; you have 7 classes per day and each class is a period (with lunch period in the middle).

Comment: @WendiKidd, I didn't exactly mean that there are different classes in each period. I meant that school days are divided into units of time called *periods* and different periods are used for different subjects, on different days of the school week.

Comment: @WendiKidd: That description of period matches with what we have in the UK, apart from "period" is the time during which a class operates. In Sixth Form (ages 17 and 18) your selection of classes may mean that you end up with a *free period*, for example, when you have an hour where your classmates are taking classes but you are not.

Comment: Shop I is first-year shop. English II is second-year English. Spanish III is third-year Spanish. This is very common vernacular in U.S. high schools. It's not unlike Composition 101, which refers to a basic composition class for college freshmen in the university environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Shop* is the traditional name in US high schools for classes in manual skills such as wood- and metal-working and auto mechanics.

*Shop I*, then would be the first-level (Roman numeral I) class in one of these skills. In this particular case it is metalworking.

ADDED:
Here are the course offerings in Shop from a rural Michigan high school. This school clearly has more limited resources than Ms. Greenbriar's:

[image]